# Java: immutable object

Tags: java

Наверное, как и всякий программист, переходящий с C++ на Java, столкнулся с проблемой отсутствия плюсового аналога константных объектов.
Конечно, понятно, что можно писать immutable интерфейсы, или дополнительную immutable версию нужного класса, или создавать копию объекта перед передачей его в функцию, или многое много другое. Но раз уж в Java нет для этого специальных средств - наверное, это было обдуманное решение. Так вот может кто-нибудь грамотно разъяснить следующие вопросы:
1) Почему же всё-таки такое решение было принято?
2) Как узнать может ли функция изменить состояние объекта?
3) Как написать функцию, чтобы люди, использующие её, не опасались изменения передаваемых объектов?
4) Аналогично для класса, чтобы у людей не возникало проблем с его использованием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут немного неясно. Как константный объект может вам гарантировать невозможность изменения внутреннего состояния объекта? Если вы вызываете метод, имеющий побочный эффект, то он просто изменит состояние объекта и всё.. и никакие внешние модификаторы вас не спасут.

Если надо сделать так, чтобы какие-то свойства (или все) класса не могли быть изменены, то **используйте final** и тогда никакой код не сможет изменить ссылку или значение.

Все внутренние свойства должны быть спрятаны. А методы не должны иметь ни малейшего намёка на возможность изменения состояния. Если это особенно важно, то можно в javadoc явно указать, что метод(ы) не имеет побочных эффектов и concurrent-safe.

Про класс.. то можно просто дать ему правильное название. Например, ImmutableMap.

Если метод называется getXXX, то это означает, что он не будет делать на самом деле set :)

Comment: Используйте final. В ранних версиях С++ можно было изменить значение константного объекта путем взятия указатели и изменения содержимого через него :-D

Comment: Константный объект и сейчас можно легко изменить через указатель на него (если только он не глобальный объект, а находится в стеке). Так что константные объекты в C\C++ на самом деле ничего не гарантируют. А у меня вполне себе современный компилятор: gcc (GCC) 4.4.3

Answer (score 1):

можно реализовать несколько уровней "сокрытия данных":

1. передаем класс у которого все поля public (паблик, метод может делать что угодно с классом)
2. передаем класс у которого все поля private, есть геттеры и сеттеры (метод может делать с классом только то что позволено)
3. передаем класс который наследует интерфейс "х" в котором описаны все геттеры (сигнатура метода соответсвенно имеет аргумент типа "х" в контракте, метод может считывать только то что позволено)
4. все как в примере 3, только каждый геттер возвращает не приватное поле а field.clone() (в этом случае если геттер возвращает не простой тип а класс, то метод не сможет изменить состояние нашего класса посредством изменения одного из полученных полей)
5. параноя: каждый геттер передаваемого обьэкта принимат в качестве параметра класс который пытается получить данные, геттер делает валидацию пермишн и возвращает результат если все ОК.

пример паранои:

```
interface JavaBeanInterface
{
   public String getId ( Object reader ) throws OurSecurityException;
}
class JavaBean implements JavaBeanInterface
{
   private final String id = null;

   public String getId ( final Object reader ) throws OurSecurityException
   {
      // throws SecurityException
      OurSecurityManager.validate ( READ, this, reader ); 
      return id;
   }
}
class SomeClass
{
   public void doSomething ( final JavaBeanInterface bean ) throws OurSecurityException
   {
      bean.getId ( this );
   }

   public void test () throws OurSecurityException
   {
      final JavaBean bean = new JavaBean ();
      doSomething ( bean );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Почему же всё-таки такое решение
> было принято?

Есть возможность изменить состояние объекта (даже private поля) через backdoor типа Reflection.

Comment: да есть, но для этого в java есть SecurityManager и система permissions, по умолчанию все дозволено, но можно кое-что и запретить. более детально здесь:[java about permissions][1]


  [1]: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/permissions.html#ReflectPermission

Comment: Это не совсем то.. речь шла о простом константном объекте и использовать SecurityManager для такого.. несколько странно. Просто константные объекты не нужны в яве в чистом виде, а нужны именно final поля.

Comment: Я имел в виду, что в Java нельзя гарантировать семантическую константность (на которую может надеятся например оптимизатор) в стиле C++, т.к. в Java существуют ШТАТНЫЕ средства для изменения состояния ЛЮБОГО объекта (с точностью до Security). В C++ же доступ к private-полям через указатели является ХАКОМ, причем теоретически возможны компиляторы, которые этого не допустят (врубят страничную защиту на сегмент объекта), видел подобное на мэйнфрейме.

Comment: А зачем это нужно? В Java такое просто не нужно. Никто не будет городить Reflection-огород, чтобы дотянуться до приватного поля. Кроме того, если поле действительно final, то через reflection вы его не сможете модифицировать, но прочесть сможете.